# IPv6 DNS Connectivity through IPv6

Tags: ipv6, web-hosting, connection, ipv4

My clients are using IPv4 in the USA. Their ISP is not ready for IPv6 yet. My public web server is on only IPv6. It is registered with a DNS Provider(GoDaddy) that is IPv4 and IPv6 enabled. Can my customers reach my web server?

Comment: In short no. I am running [a service](http://v4-frontend.netiter.com/) designed to address this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no, IPv4 client cannot connect to IPv6 server directly. However, you have options - you can setup dual-stack proxy in front of your server. This could be your own device (i.e. VPC or Load balancer on Linode, Rackspace or any other dual-stack provider) or you could use service like CloudFlare.

Answer (score 2):

IPv4 and IPv6 are completely different protocols. An IPv4-only client cannot directly connect to an IPv6-only server.

The IPv4-only clients can get a free IPv6 tunnel from places like Hurricane Electric.The clients would need to have hosts which are dual-stacked with both IPv4 and IPv6.